# How to read and display a .csv file on a Tornado server?

Tags: python, csv, http, webserver, tornado

I have been trying to read a csv file via a tornado server API and getting Error 405: Method not allowed on the following code.

```
class dataRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    uploaded_csv_file = self.request.files['data.csv'][0]
    contents = uploaded_csv_file.read_all()
    lines = contents.splitlines()
    for row in csv.reader(lines):
        self.write(' , '.join(row))
```

Additionally, I have tried making a `get` request on the same code and got an 404 Error. I want to be able to access specific columns on the csv file via a query parameter request.

Comment: Are you using a browser (and `GET`) when you're testing the RequestHandler above? You need to use POST for your code above to be run (you can use something like [REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) or `curl` for that).

Comment: `uploaded_csv_file` will be a **dict** so to access the uploaded *filename* you can use `uploaded_csv_file["filename"]` and for the *content* you want `uploaded_csv_file["body"]`.

Comment: @IonutTicus yes I am using a browser ! can you please guide me further about using `curl` ?

Comment: If you haven't heard of curl you might be better of using the REST Client for Chrome (link above). If you really want curl you can try [this](https://medium.com/@petehouston/upload-files-with-curl-93064dcccc76) tutorial for uploading files.

Comment: @IonutTicus alright looking into both the options! One last thing, will I be able to access specific column/rows with them?

Comment: RestClient and curl don't parse your data, they simply upload it (it works the same with any file type be it text, binary). The `csv` module from Python (which you already call above) will give you rows and columns.